# flutter can not generate x86, x86_64 apk file

Tags: flutter, android-install-apk

I want to generate apk file that support :
'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'

I used the command :

```
flutter build apk --flavor production
```

and also

```
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64
```

The result will always be only arm64-v8a, and armeabi-v7a

I tried to change defaultConfig in android/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "XXX"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode VERSION_CODE
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        manifestPlaceholders = [AppLabelName: "XXX"]
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk  {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
        }
    }`
```

then run

```
flutter build apk --flavor production
```

still didn't work,
When I tried to test it on

```
ASUS T00P • EAAZCY03U504 • android-arm • Android 4.4.2 (API 19)
```

it always show error

```
Performing Push Install
build\app\outputs\apk\production\release\app-production-release.apk: 1 file pushed. 3.5 MB/s (33320272 bytes in 9.085s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-production-release.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE]
```

Comment: Sorry, seems my problem is not related to x86 structure, it's about multiDex setting. I fixed by [official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)  and [how to override attachBaseContext](https://github.com/PSPDFKit/pspdfkit-flutter/blob/master/example/android/app/src/main/java/com/pspdfkit/flutter/example/FlutterExampleApplication.java)

Comment: And currently, flutter doesn't support x86 binaries until this November. [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9253)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the [official documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#what-are-the-supported-target-architectures) stated that support building for x86 Android is not yet available:

> When building your application in release mode, Flutter apps can be
> compiled for
> [armeabi-v7a](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#v7a) (ARM
> 32-bit),
> [arm64-v8a](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#arm64-v8a)
> (ARM 64-bit), and
> [x86-64](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#86-64) (x86
> 64-bit). Flutter does not currently support building for x86 Android
> (See [Issue 9253](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9253)).

And [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/faq#what-devices-and-os-versions-does-flutter-run-on) as well:

> - We support and test running Flutter on a variety of low-end to high-end platforms. For a detailed list of the platforms on which we
>   test, see the list of [supported
>   platforms](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/supported-platforms).
> - Flutter supports building ahead-of-time (AOT) compiled libraries for `x86_64`, `armeabi-v7a`, and `arm64-v8a`.
> - Apps built for ARMv7 or ARM64 run fine (using ARM emulation) on many x86 Android devices.
> - We support developing Flutter apps on a range of platforms. See the system requirements listed under each [development operating
>   system](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install).

Regarding the support for building in x86 (32 bit), it was mentioned in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9253#issuecomment-545082953):

> On master, Flutter now supports the x86_64 (64 bit) Android ABI. The
> engine also has support for building in x86 (32 bit) by following
> instructions at
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/JIT-Release-Modes